# Open new Page from an Xbap

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xbap

Our application is an Xbap running in full trust. I have a function similar to this:

```
private void ShowPage(Page page)
{
    NavigationWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as NavigationWindow;  
    mainWindow.Navigate(page);
}
```

This works great for browsing inside an existing window. I would like to open this new page in a separate window. Is there anyway to do this?

There is an overload that takes 'extraData' but I haven't been able to determine what to pass to navigate to a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently WPF is a little new for StackOverflow. Here is the function I came up with in case anyone else stumbles across this.

```
private void ShowPage(Page page)
{
    NavigationWindow popup = new NavigationWindow();  
    popup.Height = 400;
    popup.Width = 600;
    popup.Show();
    popup.Navigate(page);
}
```

I have not tried this in partial trust, it is likely this only works in full trust.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this would only work in Full Trust.  You cannot create a popup in partial trust.